# In practice, would a custom Double class be much slower than the built-in double?

Tags: c++

So suppose I do something like

```
class Double {
  double m_double;
public:
  Double() { }
  Double(double d) : m_double(d) { }
  operator double() const { return m_double; }
  operator double&() { return m_double; }
};
```

Maybe I later want to extend this to make NaN a bit more friendly (by adding a bool say), etc.

My question is, do you think off the top of your head that this Double (and possible extensions on it) would be "measurably" slower than using the built-in double directly?

If you have some experience in working with large data sets, with vectors, copying/moving around vectors of such data, etc. - I hope you can give me some concrete insights/pointers/tips regarding this topic based on your experience.

Comment: As it is, this will have zero overhead, _if_ you add a correct default constructor.  (Also, having `const` members is a bad idea)

Comment: Would the object be larger than a native double due to alignment/padding etc?  Could easily do a sizeof to test.

Comment: @user2015453 what do you really want to archive?

Comment: In C++11, NaN is rather easily checked. [std::isnan](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan) returns a bool when given a double. Wrapping double in a class and properly including it everywhere would probably be more annoying than including cmath where you need it.

Comment: I think it'll be slower since more assignments are made, but you could easily do a benchmark.

Comment: It _will_ be a bad idea if you share this code with others (or you come back to this in a couple of months), as there will most likely be some confusion about what `Double` is, or why a `double` [sic] have methods. Not to mention some people (possible even yourself) will write `double` when they mean `Double` and the other way around.

Comment: It may be an interesting exercise but I'd be reluctant to use something like this in production.

Comment: With all the methods inlined it would have good performance.  Of course measurements are always a good idea.

Comment: Speed aside, this will cause you nothing but headaches. Having a type that can be **constructed from** a builtin type and **converted to** a builtin type leads to many ambiguities. If you really, really, really want to do this, make the conversions `explicit`. Then you'll have to add casts wherever you need to convert your type to the builtin type, but at least the code will compile sensibly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern compilers do excellent optimizations. Single scalar en-wrapped in a class usually performs as well as plain one. If you add additional checking into member operators then it will cost just what you added. If you need to apply additional limitations to double then that is good idea.

**Example:** `std::array<T,N>` it is ... in essence just an array. I have failed to find test that demonstrates any overhead when comparing to raw array. The added limitations and container-like functionality make it valuable.

Avoid having operators that convert silently to scalars like `operator double()`. Compilers apply implicit conversions to typos with amazing ease and sometimes achieve that defects compile. Later it takes some time to realize why it is working like it is. Make the conversions more explicit like `double raw() const`. The resulting code is easier to understand and runs as fast.

**Example:** `std::array<T,N>` does not convert to raw pointer to first element like ordinary array. User has to use `&a[0]` to get raw pointer to first element. That makes it lot safer and easier to understand in code. It works as quickly (cost of the operation is 0 in optimized code).